# How can I declare and assign values to variables in Oracle SQL Developer for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, variables, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've been researching and have tried numerous ways to declare and assign values to variables for a PostgreSQL database using Oracle SQL Developer to no avail. This is what I am trying to do:

```
DEFINE response = '0'
DEFINE startDate = TO_TIMESTAMP('2020/03/28 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS');
DEFINE endDate = TO_TIMESTAMP('2020/03/30 19:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS');

SELECT clog.ch_call_index
      ,clog.ch_response AS "Response"
      ,cdata.ch_final_disposition AS "Result"
      ,clog.ch_spoken
      ,cdata.ch_recorded_msg AS "Recorded Message"
      ,cdata.ch_menu_selections AS "Menu Selections"
      ,clog.ch_spoken_dt_tm
      ,clog.ch_response_dt_tm
FROM ch_call_log clog
INNER JOIN ch_call_data cdata ON clog.ch_call_index = cdata.ch_call_index
WHERE cdata.ch_start_dt_tm >= &startDate
AND cdata.ch_start_dt_tm <= &endDate
AND (SELECT ch_response
     FROM ch_call_log
     WHERE ch_call_index = clog.ch_call_index
     ORDER BY ch_spoken_dt_tm DESC
     LIMIT 1) = '&&response'
AND clog.ch_response = '&&response'
ORDER BY cdata.ch_final_disposition
```

The following works just fine but I would like to figure out how to use variables and easily update them when needed:

```
SELECT clog.ch_call_index
      ,clog.ch_response AS "Response"
      ,cdata.ch_final_disposition AS "Result"
      ,clog.ch_spoken
      ,cdata.ch_recorded_msg AS "Recorded Message"
      ,cdata.ch_menu_selections AS "Menu Selections"
      ,clog.ch_spoken_dt_tm
      ,clog.ch_response_dt_tm
FROM ch_call_log clog
INNER JOIN ch_call_data cdata ON clog.ch_call_index = cdata.ch_call_index
WHERE cdata.ch_start_dt_tm >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2020/03/28 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')
AND cdata.ch_start_dt_tm <= TO_TIMESTAMP('2020/03/30 19:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')
AND (SELECT ch_response
     FROM ch_call_log
     WHERE ch_call_index = clog.ch_call_index
     ORDER BY ch_spoken_dt_tm DESC
     LIMIT 1) = '0'
AND clog.ch_response = '0'
ORDER BY cdata.ch_final_disposition
```

Comment: Does Oracle SQL Developer actually work with Postgres? Isn't that an Oracle only tool?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name for migrations to Oracle Database, ONLY

Comment: With third party JDBC drivers & connectors SQL Developer can connect to many other databases other than Oracle. And it does support Postgres since 4.x I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one!

```
DECLARE start_date AS TIMESTAMP
SET start_date = TO_TIMESTAMP('2020/03/28 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: I tried that but when I run the query it still prompts me to enter values for startDate and endDate.